# Append data from table one to another - Syntax error?

Tags: sql, join, postal-code

I have two tables of zip code information, one without city and state fields (2016_Zips), the other is just a list (USZips_V1) of zip codes, the *“Zip_Code”* field is common in both tables.

I'd like to match the more complete data (with fields for city, state, latitude, longitude, etc) to the basic list of zip codes. 
This way I can see which zip codes are common for which city (big cities have multiple zip codes).

This is the code I have, but returns:

***Syntax error in expression 2016_Zips.Zip_Code***

```
SELECT USZips_V1.Zip_Code, 2016_Zips.Zip_Code, USZips_V1.city,  USZips_V1.state_id, 2016_Zips.lat, 2016_Zips.long, USZips_V1.imprecise, USZips_V1.military
FROM USZips_V1
INNER JOIN  2016_Zips ON USZips_V1.Zip_Code, 2016_Zips.Zip_Code;
```

and based it off of this:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

Here are my table headings:

This is where I want the information added:

[image]

This will be where I draw the data from to add to the table above: 
[image]
Is there a better way to do what I want to do? Is there a glaring error in my statement?

My goal in doing this is to save time matching data between the tables.

This is my expected output:
[image]

Comment: could you please provide your expected output in table format

Comment: @fa06 added a mock up of my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use `=` in your join instead `,`

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.*
FROM USZips_V1 t1
INNER JOIN  2016_Zips t2 ON t1.Zip_Code= t2.Zip_Code;
```

Comment: @PhilC  could you please sent me that error in comment

Comment: _Syntax error in query expression '2016_Zips.Zip_Code'_

Comment: @PhilC could you please create your table here https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hnff3zeH6aM83RrGhf1fJJ/0 in fiddle so i can check where you are doing mistake it seems to me there is typo in your sql

Comment: @PhilC i edited my answer could you please check  does it works or not , it suppose to be worked if your provided table and column name is correct

Answer (score 0):

Always use Explicit `JOIN`

```
SELECT u.Zip_Code, z.Zip_Code, u.city,  z.state_id, z.lat, z.long, u.imprecise, z.military
FROM USZips_V1 AS u
INNER JOIN  2016_Zips AS z ON u.Zip_Code=z.Zip_Code;
```

Comment: Your abbreviations don't make sense. Please explain, as this did not run either...

Comment: @PhilC It was just an alias used for quick coding